# Jquery Add active class to main menu

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, menu

I'm trying to add dynamic active class to my main menu, but i can't able to achieve this,

My jquery is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navi a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

My main menu is,

```
<ul id="navi">
  <li><a href="#">About MHG</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Workout Programs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
  <li><a href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can this possibly work when the `href` attribute of all the `a` elements are set to `#`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">About MHG</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Workout Programs</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**jquery**

```
$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1/

Comment: This won't work on pages that completely reload, only that partially reload and let the menu just be.

Answer (score 1):

^^ same as above comment by Rory!!

, if you still need you can do

```
$("#navi a").live("click", function(){
  $("#navi a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active")
});
```

If you have all the links pointing to a same page above solution works, as i see you going to traverse from one page to another this wont work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This method will check the page URL that the user is visiting, then add the active class in `<li>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="member.php">Member</a></li>
        <li><a href="project.php">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="activity.php">Activity</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var setActive = function () {

    // Get the last item in the path (e.g. index.php)
    let url = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

    // Add active nav class based on url
    $("#nav ul li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == url || $(this).attr("href") == '') {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
        }
    })

    // Add the active class into Home if user omit index.php from url
    if (url == '') {
        $("#nav ul li").eq(0).addClass("active");
    }
};

$(function () {
    setActive();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear. By active if you mean the list-item you are hovering on then it should be something like this:

```
$('a.menu').hover(

function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
},

function () {
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
});
```