# Current menu link in nevigation bar must stay highlighted

Tags: java, css, liferay

On navigation bar once i clicked on any menu like (Home), home link is active but doesn't stay highlighted.

Unable to find the solution.

Comment: Please show some code. Or provide a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically add active class to menu item and add suitable style to it.
**HTML**

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">About MHG</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Workout Programs</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**jquery**

```
$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

## [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1/)

Reference - [Jquery Add active class to main menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607480/jquery-add-active-class-to-main-menu)