# Change color on menu link when selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to change the color of the selected menu link. When a menu is selected the user is redirected to that URL and I want that link to change color. The page reloads when the link is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entry-link > ul li').click(function(e) {
    $('.entry-link > ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.entry-links > ul li.selected {
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="entry-links">
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#~/" title="För elever">För elever</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/for-skolpersonal/" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/ungdom-och-elevdatabas/" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I don't get an error but nothing is happening

Comment: you are adding and removing the same class on the same element?

Comment: You forgot to put dot before classname in jquery funtion.(**.entry-link**).and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607480/jquery-add-active-class-to-main-menu.

Comment: Does the whole page reload? Then you need to add a class to highlight. Or do you want to highlight the item unde the curser? Then you need the :hover selector, instead of selected.

Comment: @BlindSeer The whole page reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

      $('.entry-links  a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.entry-links > ul li').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).parent().addClass('selected');             


      });
  });
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t64d1obe/18/

Answer (score 0):

You put entry-links in some places and entry-link in another

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entry-links ul li').click(function(e) {
    $('.entry-links ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.entry-links ul .selected {
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="entry-links">
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#~/" title="För elever">För elever</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/for-skolpersonal/" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/ungdom-och-elevdatabas/" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Not working. When the link is clicked and the page reloads, the change disappears.

Answer (score 0):

use window.localStorage or window.sessionStorage to store the color of link and set the color from the stored variable

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link you get redirected to a new page.
So just before the http request ask for a new page, your javascript tells the page to change appearance.

what i think you are trying to do is mark the currently selected page.
You can do this in your html by adding the class `selected` to the current page menu like:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
li.selected {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
li.selected a {
  color: white;
}
lo.selected a:visited {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="entry-links">
  <ul>
    <li class="selected">
      <a href="" title="För elever">För elever</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" title="För skolpersonal">För skolpersonal</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" title="Ungdom och elevdatabas">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or you can use javascript to detect what page you are currently on and add the selected class to the correct element that way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;
  console.log(hrefString);

  var aNodes = $('.menu').find('a');

  aNodes.each(function(index) {
    if ($(aNodes[index]).attr('href') == hrefString) {
      $(aNodes[index]).parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.active a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="http://stacksnippets.net/js">Link to current page</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="_blank">Other page</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="_blank">other link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="_blank">etc</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(Or with javascript not recommended)
Add a javascript to each page and adds selected class to the correct menu link. Just hard coded javascript style change (again not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

ok ,
first off all  [ $('entry-link > ul li') ] this is not valid selector.
you must use a css identifier.
like [for class (.)] etc..
so use the selector as

```
$('.entry-link > ul li');
```

the (.) is important

and test the demo i post . it may sold the problem easily [ use hover ].

[visit the DEMO](https://jsbin.com/putoni/edit?html,css,js,output)